# How does expression parser in System.Linq.Dynamic work?

Tags: .net, linq, dynamic, expression

Well, I am trying to grasp how the expression parser in `System.Linq.Dynamic` dll works, but the logic is a little bit obscure. `ParseExpression()` calls `ParseLogicalOr()`, this one in turn calls `ParseLogicalEnd()` and so on... Could you please give some advice on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically looking for each type of expression. the odd part is it calls the methods in decreasing priority, each of which first calls the one with next highest priority.

`Or` has lowest priority, so it calls `And` which has next lowest, which calls `Comparison`, which calls `Add`, and so on until it gets to `Primary`.

The best way to understand code like this is to debug it.  Include the source in your solution and then create a small test app with a few different expressions, starting out simple and getting more complex.  Then step through each one until you understand the whole thing.  It'll be come clear after you do that.

Comment: Well, thank you. This is exactly what I didn't get in the whole library implementation, but I am still wondering how to determine which method has lower or higher priority and why.

Comment: @QuéPadre, it's confusing because the first method calls in turn calls the second before it does it's own processing.  Therefore the first method called, Or, has the lowest priority.